# What are some chemical engineering bottlenecks for a perfectly synthetic meat?

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry

Recently, the Impossible Burger has become more and more popular. It seems to be a very big effort and even making it's way to the top restaurants. Of course, this has been something that scientists have been working on for decades and is a mix of sciences such as gastronomy, chemistry and others.

In such experiments as the Impossible Burger, I keep hearing neuroscientists and flavour experts trying to replicate the smells, the texture and other characteristics by what I understand it to be brute testing (although I am sure they do some biological and chemical modelling to supplement the engineering process). What it got me thinking about was what are some bottlenecks to making a PERFECT replica of meat. As a mechanical engineer graduate myself, my knowledge is limited on the issue. What holds back chemical engineers and scientist to identify the contents of meat and exactly produce a synthetic copy? We have techniques like IR spectroscopy and many other advanced methodologies for identifying chemicals. Is it a manufacturing complexity or is it just another case of expensive computational costs and insufficient observational techniques to fully figure out the structure of meat?